# Error inflating animation resource

Tags: android, layout, animation, drawable

I read [this example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) and I'm trying to use it. I put this in drawable folder as `somth.xml`:

```
 <animation-list android:id="selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img2" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

I also put it in anim folder I try to add header like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

But give me an error like this:

> Error in an XML file: aborting build.

What is wrong?

Comment: Which API level are you using? Are you certain that the compilation error is coming from this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, it seems that `android:id` is [not a valid attribute for frame animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame).

Try removing that attribute and/or adding `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to `<animation-list>`.

Answer (score 0):

had you inserted required drawable? or you can clean and build the project

```
Eclipse>Project>clean
```